# Android device orientation in Layar

Tags: android, orientation, layar

I'm developing an application that creates a mock GPS provider and sends a fixed location to Layar. When my layer launches I can see in the map that I'm on the correct location I've provided and it doesn't jump around, but the objects sometimes appear to be in wrong positions.
I'm using the device on a street, outdoors, and I've got points parallel to the street. Sometimes the direction is so wrong that it almost position all objects perpendicular to the street.

Any info on how to correct this situation? Or any suggestion of why does the direction sometimes points in the wrong direction?